# Codeigniter dynamic website uri routing and content

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a dynamic website.

The website is like this: you have the country map with hyperlinks to every cites and from cites link to information about the cities who you have chosen.

The cities content and the information content will be loaded dynamic form database.

Something like: www.website.com/countrymap/cities/information/

These pages are routed to countrymap page.

I have this code in routes.php

$route['countrymap/(.*)'] = 'countrymap/index/$1';

If I access the www.website.com/countrymap/newyork/ or www.website/countrymap/newyork/information/ or other else after countrymap/ I have the same content as countrymap page, the title, the content page, all is the same as www.website.com/countrymap

How can I put different titles, on these pages, different content ?

And I don't like this form www.website.com/countrymap/cities/information/ I want something like this:  www.website.com/countrymap-cities-information

How can i route to form with "-" not with "/".

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routing in Codeigniter is really pretty awesome! Your code is almost done,just need some modification in your config/route file. follow below code...

```
$route['countrymap/(:any)'] = 'countrymap/index/$1';
```

For more you may follow [Codeigniter official Routing page](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html).

Thank you!

Comment: How can I change uri routing from www.site.com/countrymap/cities/information/ to www.site.com/countrymap-cities-information/ because I don't like with "/" I prefer with "-"  Thank you !